# Obtain bounding boxes from Tensorflow Object Detection model

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am using the following code to get the bounding box positions of objects in an image.

```
    image = Image.open(image_path)
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)  
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
    output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(    
        image_np,
        output_dict['detection_boxes'],
        output_dict['detection_classes'],
        output_dict['detection_scores'],
        category_index,
        instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=2)
    plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
    plt.imshow(image_np)

    width = 1024
    height = 600

    for i,j in zip(output_dict['detection_boxes'],output_dict['detection_scores']):
        if(j>0.5):
            print(i[0]*width,i[2]*height,i[1]*width,i[3]*height)
```

The size of the test image is (1024,600). The above code outputs the following

```
456.1627197265625 433.97676944732666 659.828125 562.1794939041138
430.4501953125 364.17006254196167 612.30224609375 440.01832008361816
453.7798156738281 326.9976854324341 584.5558471679688 374.18121099472046
```

which I think is in the order of `x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max`
Please let me know if this the expected/desired output and if not, how do I modify my code?

Comment: If you want the order above, the print line should be `print(i[1]*width,i[0]*height,i[3]*width,i[2]*height)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. So just for clarification, the bounding boxes I get will be relative to (1024,600)  image size right?

Comment: yes. You can try plotting the box on image